# How to solve the "symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64" in M1 Mac

Tags: c++, macos, g++, arm64

new user of Mac OS I can't compile the c++ code.

This topic is related to :  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425361/ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-clang-linker-command-failed)  and [this](https://github.com/exercism/exercism/issues/5476)

I tried the methods mentioned but it doesn't work.

````
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Menu::affichageMenu()", referenced from:
      _main in note_soft-276eef.o
  "Menu::setC(int)", referenced from:
      _main in note_soft-276eef.o
  "Menu::choice()", referenced from:
      _main in note_soft-276eef.o
  "Menu::Menu()", referenced from:
      _main in note_soft-276eef.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```{shell}
I need your help knowing that I rarely use c++ to code.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425361/ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-clang-linker-command-failed
  [2]: https://github.com/exercism/exercism/issues/5476
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved with 2 types of actions:

1. manage compilation with cmake
2. or put all files (headers and sources files) in the same directory